# User defined csv export in highcharts

Tags: java, jquery, highcharts

I want to define a CSV export in highcharts. But i dont want the data which is there on graph . But want the complete detail of that data in CSV . is it possible?

I have separate JSON for csv.

Comment: do you want to convert json to csv?

Comment: do you have json object and you want to convert your json object to csv file ?

Comment: So I have 2 json. One i have to draw chart and another one i want to use it as CSV export in highcharts

Comment: this link can help you

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/565920/Create-CSV-from-JSON-in-Csharp

Comment: I want it on completely client side with jquery. And to be more specific. does Highchart provide any hack for it

Comment: you should write own method "convert to csv" to handle this functionality trough javascript function with json parameter

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sturtevant/vunf9/

Comment: There is an Export-CSV Plugin for Highcharts that allows exporting data of a chart into CSV - [http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/7/Export%20Data](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/7/Export%20Data)